# How to scroll text within a card body to left when hovering the card-body text

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a Bootstrap 5 `card-body` with a `card-title` and `card-text` with texts inside the `card-body` class. How can I style my CSS so that the `card-title` will automatically scroll horizontally when hovering over the `card-title`?

Example:

```
<div className="card-body ">
  <h5 style={{ textAlign: "center" }} className="card-title">
    <Link to={`/show/${userShow.show.id}`} className="stretched-link" id="links">
    <span style={{ fontWeight: "bold", color: "white" }}> {userShow.show.name} </span>
    </Link>
  </h5>
  <span className="card-text">
    <h6 style={{
   textAlign: "center",
   fontSize: "14px",
   fontWeight: 400,
   color: "white",
   }}> {" "} {userShow.show.publisher} </h6>
  </span>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://css-tricks.com/scrollbars-on-hover/) great article explaining how to do this.

```css
.content {
  padding: 17px 0 17px 17px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  mask-image: linear-gradient(to top, transparent, black),
    linear-gradient(to left, transparent 17px, black 17px);
  mask-size: 100% 20000px;
  mask-position: left bottom;
  -webkit-mask-image: linear-gradient(to top, transparent, black),
    linear-gradient(to left, transparent 17px, black 17px);
  -webkit-mask-size: 100% 20000px;
  -webkit-mask-position: left bottom;
  transition: mask-position 0.3s, -webkit-mask-position 0.3s;
}

.content:hover {
  -webkit-mask-position: left top;
}

@keyframes background {
  from {
    background: pink;
  }
  to {
    background: #c0d6ff;
  }
}

.wrapper {
  float: left;
  animation: background 5s infinite alternate;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="content">
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you mean a [marquee effect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/marquee).

The code below can create a marquee that scrolls only when you `mouseover` it, however I have been unable to make it stop by default, the `onshow` and `onload` properties don't seem to work.

```
<marquee
    onmouseover="this.start()"
    onshow="this.stop()"
    onload="this.stop()"
    onmouseout="this.stop()"
>
    Card heading
</marquee>
```

Comment: is this automatic scrolling back and forth? I would like to achieve the scrolling only when hovering!

Comment: There is currently a bug to this code. You need to invoke `this.stop` to make it stop scrolling, and it does work **after you have hovered over the element at least once**.

So, I tried calling `this.stop` at `onshow` and `onload` but doesn't seem to solve the issue. Let me know if you find a way to stop it by default. I'm looking for a way as well.

Answer (score 0):

add css like this:

```
.card-body:hover .card-title{
 position: relative;
 animation: scroll  2s infinite;
      }
@keyframes scroll {
  0%,
  100% {
    margin-left: 0;
  }

  50% {
    margin-left: 200px;
  }
}
```

Comment: Hmm, this just moves my card-title to the left

Comment: It actually doesnt do what I wanted! This doesn't scroll to the left, it just moves all my text to the left, like adding padding left to it. Any other helpful tips? :(

Comment: Updated the code. This will work now. Here is the example: https://codepen.io/ahnayef/pen/jOYGxXz